# System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' when converting to Decimal

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to calculate the price of an item.

When the user picks the item, it will be shown in a Label. Then when the user clicks on the Label, it will display the total price in a TextBox.

I've done this before, but now an error pops up

> System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

```
Private Sub Label2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblCalcTable.Click
    itemcost(0) = Convert.ToDecimal(tbSpagehti.Text) * Price_Spagethi
    itemcost(1) = Convert.ToDecimal(tbNachos.Text) * Price_Nachos

    Dim total As Decimal

    If cbBeefSteak.Checked Or cbNachos.Checked = True Then
        total = itemcost(0) + itemcost(1)
    End If

    tbTotal.Text = total
```

[image]

How can I correct this?

Comment: The exception is clear that the input data is not recognized as a valid `decimal` value. Check what each textbox contains before converting.

Comment: `Convert.ToDecimal` or the more appropriate `Decimal.Parse` parse data using *the user's locale*. If the user enters the wrong decimal separator, or enters text instead of digits, the methods will fail.

Comment: Just a thought, an empty text box is not zero. It is an empty string which cannot be converted to decimal. You either need to test for empty text boxes or assure that a 0 is in each unfilled box.

Comment: For the text box I alr already make only number can be enter.....I will try check it again

Answer (score 2):

You can use Decimal.TryParse() to help you validate whether or not the value is the type of data you want.

```
Dim GoodItemCost as Decimal
If Decimal.TryParse(tbSpagehti.Text, GoodItemCost) then
     itemcost(0) = GoodItemCost * Price_Spagethi
Else
     '' display an error message
End If
```